# Is it technically possible to solo mine bitcoin using cpu without a pool? How? Ubuntu

Tags: cpu, cpuminer

For development reasons I'd like to have a private "real" bitcoin mainnet network.
Bitcoin-core doesn't support mining any more.

I have set up a network of 2 nodes (using connect conf command).
CPUminer is designed (as far as I know) to connect to a mining pool server.

Any idea how to directly do cpu solo mining with bitcoin?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that thread. They are only loosely related.

Comment: Perhaps update the title of the question to reflect this is about a private test network. It does look very much like a duplicate right now.

Answer (score 3):

For development it's often helpful to start both nodes in regression test mode (regtest mode). The developer has his own private blockchain and can choose when to create a new block. You can use `bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 1` to generate a new block.

For more information see [Developer Examples - Regtest Mode](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#regtest-mode).

Comment: I know all that but I don't like having different addresses. I want a 100% bitcoin network that produces a block every 10 minutes, etc. The real thing but private. I am developing a rather complex app and I need to test it as real as possible.

Answer (score 0):

cpuminer does work for solo mining.  I've used it successfully on the BCH testnet.

I don't have the exact command line handy right now, but if you can't figure it out, I can try to dig it up.

Comment: I thought I could do solo mining and tried and tried ( ./minerd  --threads=1 --coinbase-addr=3GGvSvodq8Gp5pjWZxhihBxo4gEtSjKtKo -o http://127.0.0.1:8332  -O xxx:yyy --no-longpoll --no-getwork --no-stratum ) until I realized I had to set a mining pool server which I don't know how to do. So I wonder if there is a software to do solo mining.

Comment: No, you don't have to set up a mining pool server.  cpuminer can connect directly to your bitcoind.  When I have some time, I can try to look up the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I finally learn that mainnet has (among many other things) checkpoints (certain blocks with their hash hard coded and check they agree with the blockchain).
So starting a private mainnet it's simply not possible (wihtout touching the code).